# Properties of unit vector scaling

Tags: optimization, vectors, normed-spaces

What properties are kept when we scale a vector to unit length, i.e.  $\frac{\mathbf{v}}{||\mathbf{v}||_1}$?

Imagine that we have an unconstrained optimization problem, and we obtain as solution $x_i = k_i$. We now add $\sum x_i = 1$ as a new constraint, i.e. $\mathbf{x}$ should be unit-length.

One possibility would be to set $x_i = k_i - \frac{\sum x_i - 1}{N}$, where $N$ is the size of $\mathbf{x}$, and this can be interpreted as splitting the extra (or deficit) of $||\mathbf{x}||_1$ equally among all the values. As far as I understand, this minimizes the squared error between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{k}$.

However, this is not common. In many applications we scale $\mathbf{x}$ so that we keep  the relative distances intact: $\frac{\mathbf{x}}{||\mathbf{x}||_1}$. Why? What properties are kept by doing this? In terms of optimization, what are we minimizing/maximizing? Why would we prefer this solution over any other?

Comment: Are you asking about optimizing functions having some homogeneity property (e.g., constant along lines through the origin)...?